# How to move an oval on Canvas

Tags: javafx

After drawing an oval using fillOval(), how can I get the object by clicking on it? I want to move the oval using MouseEvents, but I can't get the object to modify it's properties with setTranslate() or something like this.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include some code of exactly what you are have accomplished and what you are still trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There simply is no such object that you could click on. The canvas just maintains an image of what you have drawn and does not have any knowledge of any objects that you may associate with these drawings.

---

For what you want to achieve the `JavaFX scene graph` is much better suited. Maybe you should read some tutorial about it.